# Attaching pre-opened IE or Process to Watin Library

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, internet-explorer-9, watin

I'm having trouble opening IE9 with -nomerge param with Watin directly, so I thought if I open IE with

> Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "-nomerge about:blank");

then attach it to Watin so I can control the browser, or either a way to attach a PID to Watin so Watin can control over it, I've tried the

> Settings.MakeNewIe8InstanceNoMerge = true;

but it didn't help at all, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the configuration globally on your work station by changing this registry entry
**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main** SessionMerging to 0